# Como hacer Recorrido en Espiral-Caracol de una Matriz n*m (no cuadrada n*n)

Tags: java, pseudocódigo

Aqui tengo este codigo para realizar una Matriz Caracol o en Espiral, su recorrido es de la posicion "0,0" hasta el medio de la matriz. 
Sin embargo no se como hacer el algoritmo para que me deja ingresar matrices n*m es decir que no sean cuadradas.. ya que al hacerlo me marca error :(

```
package matrizespiral;

import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 * Matriz Cuadrada con recorrido en Caracol o Espiral
 * 
 * Tiene doble filo el exigir la dimension de la matriz por teclado, 
 * Buscamos poder permitir mostrar el resultado de una matriz n*m tambien.
 * Pero no se como T_T
 * @author HD
 */
public class MatrizCaracolHD {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //Creando matriz con valores que da el usuario
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("--- Dimesión de la Matriz ---\n");
        System.out.println("    Ingrese numero de filas: ");
        int fil = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("    Ingrese numero de columnas: ");
        int col = sc.nextInt();
        mostrarMatriz(crearMatrizc(fil, col, 1), fil, col);

    }//finmain

    /**
     * Genera Una Matriz Caracol.
     *
     * @param fil filas dimensión de la matriz cuadrada
     * @param col columnas de la matriz.. aun en proceso de que se pueda con n*col
     * @param matrizAux numero con cual se iniciara la matriz caracol
     * @return matriz de enteros con la matriz caracol ya generada.
     */
    public static int[][] crearMatrizc(int fil, int col, int matrizAux) {

        int[][] matrizc = new int[fil + 1][col + 1];

        for (int pos = 1; pos <= fil / 2; pos++) {
            for (int i = pos; i <= col - pos; i++) {
                matrizc[pos][i] = matrizAux;
                matrizAux++;
            }
            for (int i = pos; i <= col - pos; i++) {
                matrizc[i][col - pos + 1] = matrizAux;
                matrizAux++;
            }
            for (int i = col - pos + 1; i >= pos + 1; i--) {
                matrizc[col - pos + 1][i] = matrizAux;
                matrizAux++;
            }
            for (int i = col - pos + 1; i >= pos + 1; i--) {
                matrizc[i][pos] = matrizAux;
                matrizAux++;
            }
        }
        //si la columna es impar 
        if (col % 2 == 1) {
            matrizc[col / 2 + 1][col / 2 + 1] = matrizAux;
            System.out.println("\nMatriz cuadrada IMPAR de  "+fil+" x "+col+" = "+matrizAux+" elementos");
        }else{matrizAux--;System.out.println("\nMatriz cuadrada PAR de  "+fil+" x "+col+" = "+matrizAux+" elementos");}
        return matrizc;
    }//fincrear

    /**
     * Muestra una Matriz cualquiera usando las filas y columnas como parametro
     *
     * @param matrizc matriz int[][] por mostrar
     * @param f numero de filas de la matriz por mostrar
     * @param c numero de columnas de la matriz por mostrar
     */
    public static void mostrarMatriz(int[][] matrizc, int f, int c) {
        for (int i = 1; i <= f; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j <= c; j++) {
                System.out.print(matrizc[i][j] + " \t");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }//finmostrar
}//finclass
```

Answer (score 1):

***Solución alternativa para el Recorrido Caracol.***

Depura este código y observa como trabaja linea a linea (*pues este aporte seria mas valioso yendo mas allá de un copy/paste*); Ahora, optando por unos cuantos condicionales en vez de los multiples ciclos `for` que planteas...

```
private static void mostrarMatriz( int columnas, int filas ) {
  boolean derecha = true, izquierda = false, abajo = false;
  int[][] matrizc = new int[ filas ][ columnas ];
  int x = 0, y = -1;

  for( int k = 1; k <= columnas * filas; k++ ) {
    if( izquierda ) {
      y --;
      if( y == -1 ) {
        y = 0; x --;
        izquierda = false;
      } else if( matrizc[ x ][ y ] != 0 ) {
        y ++; x --;
        izquierda = false;
      }
    } else if( derecha ) {
      y ++;
      if( y == columnas ) {
        y = columnas - 1; x ++;
        derecha = false;
        abajo = true;
      } else if( matrizc[ x ][ y ] != 0 ) {
        y --; x ++;
        derecha = false;
        abajo = true;
      }
    } else if( abajo ) {
      x ++;
      if( x == filas ) {
        x = filas - 1; y --;
        abajo = false;
        izquierda = true;
      } else if( matrizc[ x ][ y ] != 0 ) {
        y --; x --;
        abajo = false;
        izquierda = true;
      }
    } else {
      x --;
      if( x == -1 || matrizc[ x ][ y ] != 0 ) {
        x ++; y ++;
        derecha = true;
      }
    }

    matrizc[ x ][ y ] = k;
  }

  for( int i = 0; i < filas; i++ ) {
    for( int j = 0; j < columnas; j++ ) {
      System.out.print( matrizc[ i ][ j ] + "\t" );
    }
    System.out.println();
  }

  String info = filas == columnas ? "Matriz Cuadrada de " : "Matriz Rectangular de ";
  System.out.println( "[" + info + columnas + "*" + filas + " = " + columnas * filas + " elementos]" );
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;
class Prog_Genera_Matriz_Caracol
{
public static void main (String[] args)

```
{
    int n, m;
    System.out.println ("\t\tMATRIZ CARACOL");
    System.out.print ("Ingrese el valor para difinir el tamaño o dimension de filas para generar la matriz:\n");
    n = Leer.datoInt ();
    m = n;
    int[] [] M = new int [n] [m];
    mostrarM (CargarM (n, m, 1), n, m);

} //finmain


/*FUNCION leer()*/
public static int leer ()
{
    int x;
    do
    {
        System.out.print ("Introduzca un valor entero positivo: ");
        x = Leer.datoInt ();
    }while ((x <= 1) || (x % 2 == 0));    //Fin do-while
    return (x);
} //Fin Funci?n leer()


/*PROCEDIMIENTO CARGAR MATRIZ*/
public static int[] [] CargarM (int fil, int col, int matrizAux)
{

    int[] [] matrizc = new int [fil + 1] [col + 1];

    for (int pos = 1 ; pos <= fil / 2 ; pos++)
    {
        for (int i = pos ; i <= col - pos ; i++)
        {
            matrizc [pos] [i] = matrizAux;
            matrizAux++;
        }//Fin for
        for (int i = pos ; i <= col - pos ; i++)
        {
            matrizc [i] [col - pos + 1] = matrizAux;
            matrizAux++;
        }//Fin for
        for (int i = col - pos + 1 ; i >= pos + 1 ; i--)
        {
            matrizc [col - pos + 1] [i] = matrizAux;
            matrizAux++;
        }//Fin for
        for (int i = col - pos + 1 ; i >= pos + 1 ; i--)
        {
            matrizc [i] [pos] = matrizAux;
            matrizAux++;
        } //fin for
    }//Fin Procedimiento CargarM
    //si la columna es impar
    if (col % 2 == 1)
    {
        matrizc [col / 2 + 1] [col / 2 + 1] = matrizAux;
        System.out.println ("\nMatriz cuadrada IMPAR de  " + fil + " x " + col + " = " + matrizAux + " elementos");
    } //Fin if
    else
    {
        matrizAux--;
        System.out.println ("\nMatriz cuadrada PAR de  " + fil + " x " + col + " = " + matrizAux + " elementos");
    } //fin else
    return matrizc;
} //fincrear


/*PROCEDIMIENTO MOSTRAR MATRIZ*/
public static void mostrarM (int[] [] matrizc, int f, int c)
{
    for (int i = 1 ; i <= f ; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 1 ; j <= c ; j++)
        {
            System.out.print (matrizc [i] [j] + " \t");
        } //Fin for
        System.out.println ( );
    } //Fin for
} //Fin procedimiento MostarM
```

} //Finn class

Comment: Hola esto no es una respuesta, solo has publicado código sin una explicación que indique como tu código resuelve el problema.

Comment: Bienvenido a [Stack Overflow en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/) gracias por ayudar a esta comunidad. pero a tu respuesta le falta algo de contexto, dale un vistazo al siguiente contenido [Cómo responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) un saludo.